# Binary search the answer algorithm

Tags: c++, search, binary

I would like to help me with an algorithmic problem that i have been stuck for 2 days.I know that the problem can be solved with **binary search the answer** but i can not find the solution.

The problem is:
     Before some days a new road has been constructed.The length of the road is infinite to the left and right side.There are lot of applications for the  kiosks installation in the road and every owner has a preferable position in the road to install his kiosk(an integer variable a[i]),but every kiosk in the road has to be far away at most k from the previous position.There are more than one applications in each position(b[i]).The question is to find the minimum distance that is needed for the kiosk which has to travel the most.The input is n=the number of coordinates, k=the distance of two successive  kiosks, a[i]=coordinates of the applications,b[i]=the number of applications.The output should be a decimal number of double precision which denote the minimum distance of the kiosk who has traveled the most.The a[i] integers are discrete and sorted in ascending order.Lets consider for example the input:

3 2

0 1

3 2

6 1

output:1.00

2 2

0 3

1 1

output:2.50

3 1

0 5

2 1

4 5

output:3.00

Thanks in advance!

My idea is to minimize the distance which the two extreme kiosks(the kiosks that have the longer distance) will travel from their initial position.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<float.h>
#define MAX 10000000
double a[MAX],b[MAX],sum,k;
long long int n;
double min_last=1000000;
int find(double c){
  int flag=0;
  long long int i;
  double pos=c;
 // printf("inside f\n");
 // printf("%lld\n",sum);
  long long  kiosks=0;
 // printf("x=%llf\n",c);
  if(fabsf((a[0]+pos+k*(sum-1)-a[n-1]))<min_last){
     // min_last=fabs((a[0]+c+k*(sum-1)-a[n-1]));
    // printf("min_last:%lf\n",min_last);
  for( i=0;i<sum;i++){
      if(pos<=sum+a[n-1]){
         kiosks++;
//  printf("%lld %lf\n",kiosks,c);
     pos=pos+k;
         if((kiosks==sum)){
           flag=1;
       min_last=fabsf((a[0]+c+k*(sum-1)-a[n-1]));
    // printf("%lf\n",min_last);}
    }
    }
  }
}
  // printf("%d\n",flag);
   return flag;
}
double binarySearch(){
 //  printf("inside binary\n");
    double low,high,mid;
   low=-sum*k-a[n-1];
   high=sum*k+a[n-1];
  while(low<high){
       mid=low+(high-low)/2.0;
       if(find(mid)==1){
      printf("%lf\n",mid);
          low=mid;
       }
       else
          high=mid-1;
}
  return low;
}
int main(){
   long long int i;
   double x,start;
   double posx;
   double low,high,mid;
   printf("Give n,k:");
   scanf("%lld %lf",&n,&k);
  // printf("%lld %lld\n",n,k);
   printf("Give the arrays\n");
   sum=0;
  // printf("sum=%llf\n",sum);
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
//printf("%lld\n",i);
      scanf("%lf %lf",&a[i],&b[i]);
      sum=sum+b[i];
    }
  printf("%lf\n",binarySearch());
//printf("low=%lf\n",low);
start=low;
for(i=0;i<sum;i++){
      printf("kiosk %lld :%lf\t",i,start);
      start=start+k;}
      printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: We would like to see some effort on your part.  What have you tried?  Specifically, please provide some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have the option to use `std::equal_range`, `std::lower_bound`, or `std::upper_bound`. They are the built-in C++ binary searching functions.